# TCP chat room in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, socket

([Previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/262658/tcp-chat-room-in-python-3))

I've created a server file, that keeps waiting for clients. When someone connects to the server, he can send messages to the server, and from the server it is broadcasted to all clients.

Can you criticize my simple chat? Any possible improvements and changes are welcome. I have 2 classes and 2 objects files:

**Server class:**

```py
import threading
import socket


class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.host = str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
        self.port = 5050

        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind((self.host,self.port))
        self.server.listen(6)
        self.text_coding = "utf-8"      #encoding and decoding format
        self.text_length = 30           #max bytes of the messages
        self.clients = []               #stores each client reference
        self.names = []                 #stores clients names?
        self.disconnect = str("$hutdown")   #safe word to close the connection and leave the chat

    #This function sends everyone message to everyone (including the one who send)
    def broadcast(self,msg):
        for i in self.clients:
            i.send(msg.encode(self.text_coding))

    #This function removes current client name and reference from the lists above
    #And warns the server and all clients that the current client left 
    def closing_client(self,client,name):
        self.clients.remove(client)
        self.names.remove(name)

        self.broadcast(f"{name} left the chat.")
        print(f"{name} left the chat.")


    #Each client has his own thread of this function
    #This function takes each client message, to send to broadcast().
    def handle_client(self,client_reference,client_info,name):
        print(f"Connected with {name}, {client_info}")
        
        while True:
            try:

                message0 = client_reference.recv(self.text_length).decode(self.text_coding)
                message = str(message0)

                #when someone uses the key word to leave the chat
                if message == str(f"{name}: {self.disconnect}"):
                    self.closing_client(client_reference,name)
                    break
                else:
                    self.broadcast(message)

            except Exception as error:

                print("=================")
                print(error.__cause__)
                print("=================")
                self.closing_client(client_reference,name)
                break

        client_reference.close()


#This functions waits for new client
#And creates threads(of handle_client function) for each client
    def wait_new_client(self):
        while True:

            client_reference,client_info = self.server.accept()
            name = client_reference.recv(self.text_length).decode(self.text_coding)

            self.names.append(name)
            self.clients.append(client_reference)
            
            client_reference.send(str(f"Welcome {name}.").encode(self.text_coding))
            self.broadcast(str(f"{name} joined the chat."))
        
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=[client_reference,client_info,name])
            thread.start()
```

**Server file:**

```py
from Server import Server

print("Starting server...")
server0 = Server()

print("=====================")
print(f"Server is listening at {server0.host}")

server0.wait_new_client()
```

**Client class:**

```py
import socket
import threading

class Client:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.server_ip = "192.168.1.6"
        self.server_port = 5050
        self.text_lenght = 30
        self.disconnect = str("$hutdown")
        self.text_coding = "utf-8"
        self.state = True

        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.connect((self.server_ip,self.server_port))
        self.client.send(self.name.encode(self.text_coding))


    #This function waits for chat messages
    def chat_messages(self):
        while self.state:
            try:
                message = self.client.recv(self.text_lenght).decode(self.text_coding)
                print(message)

            except Exception as error:
                print("=================")
                print(error.__cause__)
                print("=================")
                self.client.close
                self.state = False

    #This function waits for user input, new message
    def write(self):
        while self.state:
            try:
                text = str(input("Digit a message: "))
                message = str(f"{self.name}: {text}")
                self.client.send(message.encode(self.text_coding))
                if text == self.disconnect:
                    self.state = False

            except Exception as error:
                print("=================")
                print(error.__cause__)
                print("=================")
                self.client.close
                self.state = False


    #This function put the above functions on threads.
    def start(self):
        try:
            chat_messages_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.chat_messages)
            write_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.write)

            chat_messages_thread.start()
            write_thread.start()
        except Exception as error:
            print("=================")
            print(error.__cause__)
            print("=================")
            self.client.close
            self.state = False
```

**Client file:**

```py
from Client import Client

name = str(input("Type your name: "))

client0 = Client(name)
client0.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things I'd like to point out

### The Server class

- It would be nice to be able to tell the server to listen on a different port, presumably by making the `Server` class' constructor take the port number as a parameter
- When you have a pair of lists that need to be kept in sync, it's often better to have a list of pairs instead. But in this case, clients presumably have unique names, so it might be nice to enforce that by having `self.clients` be a `dict` mapping names to client references
- In `handle_client`, you seem to be overusing the `str` function. It doesn't do any harm, but `message0` should already be a string after decoding so `message = str(message0)` is unnecessary, and in the `if` statement the string literal is *definitely* a string so you can just do `f"..."` instead of `str(f"...")`
- `except Exception` is a bit smelly. Like, true, you *do* want to make sure that everything gets cleaned up properly if something unexpected happens, but usually you have some idea of what might go wrong, and maybe some way to recover from some of those
- `closing_client` is a bit weird -- it removes the client from the list of known client sockets, but it doesn't take any steps to make sure it's closed. That seems like it could easily lead to a resource leak -- is there a reason that method doesn't also close the socket?

### The client class

- I feel like the constructor should definitely take the server IP and server port as parameters. Someone might want to connect to a different server
- `self.state` is a bit of a weird name -- it seems to be `True` when connected to a server and `False` otherwise, so maybe it could be called `connected` instead?
- None of the `catch` blocks actually close the socket -- they just mention the close function, but they don't call it
- `text_length` is misspelled as `text_lenght`

### The protocol in general

- There's a bit of an awkward problem where a message containing the text `"$hutdown"` it literally the same as a `$hutdown` command. This isn't that big a problem when `$hutdown` is the only thing that isn't a literal message, but maybe you want to add more commands, maybe even some that are more complex. It could be useful to explicitly distinguish messages so you know that you know what everything's supposed to be
- It feels a bit weird that clients send their own name with each message -- a confused client might find itself unable to properly `$hutdown`, and a malicious client might try to send a rude message with someone else's name on it (and I don't think this server would notice if someone did -- it only checks names when processing `$hutdown` commands, right?). The server already knows who's sending the message, so this doesn't seem necessary -- it knows what socket belongs to whom, so if "Taylor"'s socket sends "Hello" the server can figure out that it should broadcast "Taylor: Hello"
- It doesn't seem like anyone actually checks that messages are within the acceptable length. Now, most of the time any data received just gets passed straight through to a different socket or stdout, so it *usually* isn't a problem. But what if someone's name is `MyVeryVeryVeryLongNameIsCool`? That's short enough to be accepted as a name, but long enough that `MyVeryVeryVeryLongNameIsCool: $hutdown` can't fit in a single message, so they can't disconnect properly. Or what if someone sends a message like `Sam: It's pronounced with a /ŋ/`? The whole message is valid as UTF-8 text, but if you try to decode that in 30-byte chunks you break the `ŋ` in half and get a `UnicodeDecodeError`

Comment: I've been trying to understand your answer. In most part is very clear, but : 

"Or what if someone sends a message like Sam: It's pronounced
with a /ŋ/ ? The whole message is valid as UTF-8 text, but if you try to decode that in 30-byte
chunks you break the ŋ in half and get a UnicodeDecodeError"
What does it mean?

Comment: @irtexas19 A byte can only have 256 different values, and there are far more than 256 different characters, so most characters are made up of multiple bytes. For example, when you do `"".encode("utf8")` you get four bytes, not just one. If I send you 60 bytes of text and you try to handle them 30 bytes at a time, it's possible that the 30th byte is in the middle of a multi-byte character, and you can't decode just part of a character, so even if my message was valid UTF-8 text when read as a whole, the first 30 bytes on their own might not be

Comment: So should I make sure that everyone sends exactly 30bytes of message, before encoding it?

Comment: @irtexas19 That's an option - if the client expects 30-byte messages, then that's what the client should send. Though another option could be to have messages that include their own lengths, or have some sort of markers that show how long messages are, or where they begin and end, or something like that, so clients and servers can be sure to process complete messages